# how to go about detecting dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a way to implement your own mechanism to detect when dismissModalViewControllerAnimated disappears?  I've tried viewdiddisappear, but this is not being called as I think it only called when subview are removed from a view.   With the case of modals, I think iOS treats them differently.

Any ideas?

I would like my delegate to do some action after this modal view has been dismissed.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on exactly where you are trying to detect dismissModalViewControllerAnimated? A side note: dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: will be deprecated; the new method for dismissing a modal VC is dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:(completion block to be executed when animation is done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSNotificationCenter to post a notification before you dismiss the view controller.  Add your other view controllers as observers.  That's an easy way to broadcast events.

So before you dismiss:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DismissModalViewController" 
                                                    object:nil];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And then in your view controllers

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(yourCallback)
                                             name:@"DismissModalViewController" 
                                           object:nil];
```

The callback would be something like:

```
- (void) yourCallback
{
    // some code to run when modal view controller is dismissed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a delegate method that is called right before `dismissModalViewController`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parent view controller's `viewWillAppear`. By parent view controller, I mean the receiver of `presentViewController` (or `presentModalViewController`)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

The view controller that made this call, I forgot to set who the delegate was.